# Is a gamma distribution adapted when the coefficient of variation is roughly the same across observations?

Tags: gamma-distribution, coefficient-of-variation

Each observation is a distribution of values. Computing the mean $\mu_i$ and standard deviation $\sigma_i$ for each observation $i$ showed that the coefficient of variation (CV) is roughly constant across observations (the Pearson's correlation $r$ between $\{\mu_i\}$ and $\{\sigma_i\}$ is 0.5). Since proportionality between $\mu$ and $\sigma$ is a characteristic of a gamma distribution $\Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ when the shape $\alpha$ or rate $\beta$ parameter is fixed, would this be enough to provide support to use a $\Gamma$ distribution in this situation considering both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are allowed to vary when fitting a $\Gamma(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ to each observation $i$?

As an example, and for clarity, consider the distribution of feather length in birds. When looking at the feather length distribution in each bird $b_i$, and computing the associated $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$, then:
$r(\{\mu_i\}, \{\sigma_i\})=0.5$. However when fitting a gamma distribution $\Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$ to each bird, I am not using $\alpha$ fixed for the whole group of birds {$b_i$} and choosing the best $\beta_i$ for each $b_i$. Instead, I am choosing the best $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ parameters for each bird. Hence I am not sure the proportionality between $\{\mu_i\}$ and $\{\sigma_i\}$ would provide support for using a gamma distribution for this particular problem (each individual fit $\Gamma(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ certainly looks good but I would like an additional justification for using a $\Gamma$ distribution, ideally the proportionality relationship between $\{\mu_i\}$ and $\{\sigma_i\}$).

Comment: Did you try qq-plots against gamma distributions?

Comment: When CV is approximately constant, a lognormal is often a competitor because that implies working on logarithmic scale. Nothing here guarantees that gamma is best for your purposes; as @kjetilbhalvorsen implies, you still need to check fit and consider other distributions too.

Comment: Many distributional choices have constant coefficient of variation; common examples used in modeling include gamma with constant shape ($\alpha$), lognormal with constant $\sigma$ parameter, Weibull with constant shape parameter ($k$), If you don't hold those parameters constant (and it doesn't sound like you do) then you won't have constant coefficient of variation in general.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I did not try qq-plots. The data was obviously skewed, and visually the fit were very tight to the observed distribution. The idea was simply to provide another "theoretical" argument to using a gamma distribution.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you, I understand that ideally I would need to fit other distributions and compare

Comment: @Glen_b Fitting different distributions make sense. In my case I do not hold those parameters constant but I do have a "somewhat constant" coefficient of variation (r ~ 0.5 as mentioned in the post). I was wondering if that would help justifying considering a gamma but apparently not.

Comment: Quite so. It's not diagnostic. The best way to check for a gamma distribution is to fit one and (a) check how good the fit is and (b) check that you can't find a better fit with another distribution. Many people stop with (a); (b) is open-ended because there are many possible "named" distributions and many more that could be invented, but not trying (b) at all is hard to defend unless the fit is very, very good.  Copy @Glen_b